# Can I file patent for my new Automated Teller Machine?

Tags: patentability

As part of my degree project ,I *designed an automated teller machine* by adding and removing some of the existing and new features of automated teller machine and the *simulated using visual studio*.Can I able to file a patent for the same? or atleast a copyright?

Comment: You can copyright the software for sure. Whether you can patent anything depends on whether there is something novel and non-obvious over the prior art.

Comment: I didnt mean the software,I mean the new design and framework which i designed for the machine.Can i patent that one?(not the software)

Comment: My comment still holds. You'll have to determine if you infringe on any current patents and if your changes are novel and non obvious.

Comment: For one, the invention probably belongs to your university. On the other hand, this gives you the possibility to go and ask them for advice. Many universities have an office for inventions and intellectual property. They can help you better than we can. Other than that, what Eric said.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an innovative new design you could file for a design patent which is much cheaper and easier to obtain.  Apple's victories for design patent infringement cases has elevated the value of design patents in case law.  Utility patents require novel claims which you may or may not have.  They are also much more expensive to do.  If it was created with university computers or software then the university may have certain rights to it and I strongly suggest you contact them and disclose the invention.  They can either exert their rights, mark as premature or give the rights back to you. Many universities have departments that create businesses or licenses based on certain inventions ...  UF's Gatorade franchise for instance.